# How do I add a vocabulary to a metadata in the item's metadata edit form in DSpace 6.x xmlui

Tags: user-interface, edit, dspace

I can add a vocabulary to a metadata in the submission form while creating an item.
However, when I try to edit the item, I do not see the vocabulary to select the value from. I could not find any documentation relating to customizing the edit form for an item. Can anyone point me to the right direction?
I am using version 6.x of DSpace.

Screenshot of edit item form

[image: 1]

Screenshot after enabling authority control

[image: 2]

Comment: If you enabled controlled vocabulary for that specific metadata, there should be a lookup button beside that metadata entry (assuming it is subject type metadata and not dropdowns like type and language).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As you pointed out, there is a lookup button beside that metadata in the submission form when I first create a metadata(as an author/submitter) but I only see the textarea with the entered values when I try to edit the item's metadata (as an editor/administrator) after an item is already created and approved.

Comment: Assuming you use the vocabulary `srsc` for `dc.subject`, you have to tell DSpace the plugin to use, e.g. `choices.plugin.dc.subject = srsc`. Please see my answer below. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only see the lookup button beside that metadata in the submission form because that is for the submission process only. You have to tell DSpace that that metadata is authority controlled. Please see this link: [Authority Control of Metadata Values](https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC6x/Authority+Control+of+Metadata+Values)

Assuming we will use `srsc` as the controlled vocabulary, your settings should look like below. Note the last line, e.g. `authority.controlled.dc.subject= true`, that tells DSpace that the `dc.subject` field is authority controlled. You can find this settings in `dspace.cfg` under the `#####  Authority Control Settings  #####` header but you can override it by putting it in `local.cfg`.

```
## demo: subject code autocomplete, using srsc as authority
## (DSpaceControlledVocabulary plugin must be enabled)
## Warning: when enabling this feature any controlled vocabulary configuration in the input-forms.xml for the metadata field will be overridden.
choices.plugin.dc.subject = srsc
choices.presentation.dc.subject = lookup
vocabulary.plugin.srsc.hierarchy.store = true
vocabulary.plugin.srsc.hierarchy.suggest = true
vocabulary.plugin.srsc.delimiter = "::"
authority.controlled.dc.subject= true
```

Also, make sure that DSpace Controlled vocabulary is enabled, i.e., `webui.controlledvocabulary.enable = true` and:

```
plugin.selfnamed.org.dspace.content.authority.ChoiceAuthority = \
   org.dspace.content.authority.DCInputAuthority, \
   org.dspace.content.authority.DSpaceControlledVocabulary
```

exists.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right direction. I read the document in the link that you shared. I made the changes in the file dspace.cfg as per your suggestion. <code> choices.plugin.dc.subject = srsc
choices.presentation.dc.subject = lookup
vocabulary.plugin.srsc.hierarchy.store = true
vocabulary.plugin.srsc.hierarchy.suggest = true
vocabulary.plugin.srsc.delimiter = "::"
authority.controlled.dc.subject = true </code> However, I can't see the Lookup button as given in the screenshot in the document. Did I miss anything else?

Comment: @KiranDhakal Did you restart the Tomcat service?

Comment: Yes I did restart the Tomcat service. I can see the Thumbs up icon and lock/unlock button. But I am not able to see the Lookup button.

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the form after the configuration changes in the question.

Comment: @KiranDhakal, Make sure controlled vocabulary is enabled, i.e. `webui.controlledvocabulary.enable = true`. Don't forget to restart Tomcat if you edit this in `dspace.cfg`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I can now see the Lookup button after I enabled the controlled vocabulary and uncommented the lines 
`plugin.selfnamed.org.dspace.content.authority.ChoiceAuthority = \
   org.dspace.content.authority.DCInputAuthority, \
   org.dspace.content.authority.DSpaceControlledVocabulary`
in the file dspace.cfg. But when I click on the Lookup button, I see a flat list of terms and not a hierarchical list. I am not sure why.

Comment: @KiranDhakal, unfortunately, the hierarchical structure is only displayed during the submission process (based from my experience when using the controlled vocabulary xml).